# Прямая ссылка на видео youtube

Tags: php, youtube

Столкнулся с проблемой прямой ссылки на видео YouTube. Хочу, что бы при вводе в поле ссылки на YouTube, само видео скачивалось на сервер. Буду признателен, если расскажете, как это сделать со всеми мелочами. Заранее спасибо.

Видео по ссылкам, которые выходят, не открывается:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents("https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=030YR0Fwb4s");
    parse_str($data);
    $arr = explode(",", $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        parse_str($item, $vdata);
        print_r($vdata);
    }
?>
```

Comment: а вам стоить уточнить вопрос, как пытались сделать и на каком шаге возникла проблема

Comment: Надеюсь так будет лучше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот вопрос подробно раскрыт в [статье на habrahabr.ru](https://habrahabr.ru/post/137496/).

Насколько показали мои простые опыты в браузерном JS с двумя разными видео-роликами с youtube - если что-то и изменилось с момента написания статьи, то незначительно. Бегло ознакомившись с ней я попробовал следующее:

Нашел свежий ролик, загруженный 26.06.2016: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iI0Sw4eS1TE
Использовав id видео из ссылки открыл адрес https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=iI0Sw4eS1TE
и скачал файл, содержащий длинную строку данных. Далее, перешел в редактор javascript и накидал следующий код:

```
//исходная строка
var str = 'содержимое загруженного файла';
//функция для создания уникальных ключей. дальше рассказано зачем.
var genKey = function(key, arr){
    if(arr[key]){
        key = key+1;
        return genKey(key, arr);
    } else {
        return key;
    }   
}
//из строки запроса делает ассоциативный массив. 
var parseQuery = function(s){
    var t = s.split('&');
    var query = {}; 
    for(var k in t){
        var t2 = t[k].split('=');
        //выяснилось, что в данных под url_encoded_fmt_stream_map ключи повторяются (url=*&url=*&url=*). Чтобы избежать перезаписи ключей применил простейшую функцию genKey.
        var key = genKey(t2[0], query);
        query[key] = t2[1];
    }    
    return query;
};

//получаем массив данных раскодируя исходную строку
var tmp = parseQuery(str);
//под ключом url_encoded_fmt_stream_map находим интересующий нас список урлов. он в urlencoded-виде.
var encodedStreamMap = tmp['url_encoded_fmt_stream_map'];
//превращаем с массив данные из url_encoded_fmt_stream_map, предварительно сделав urldecode строки.
var stream_map = parseQuery(decodeURIComponent(encodedStreamMap));

//под ключом "url" в массиве находится ссылка на самое качественное видео (по моим двум экспериментам, по крайней мере)
var url = decodeURIComponent(stream_map['url']);
```

*"живые" данные не добавил, т.к. они слишком объемные и содержат мои идентификаторы, лучше используйте свои.*

В переменной url, в итоге, оказывается ссылка на видео, при открытии которой в браузере сразу начинается скачивание.

Естественно, я не призываю писать все этой на JS (хотя, почему бы и не node.js), я лишь демонстрирую действия, при которых у меня все получилось. Код можно переписать на PHP или что-то другое.

Возможно, итоговая ссылка не захочет открываться на других машинах, но автор статьи на habrahabr говорит об этом и дает рекомендации, как поступить в этом случае. А именно - удалить из url все идентификационные данные. По мнению автора, это "все параметры после id". Конкретно в моем случае это следующие ключи (пригодится, если порядок изменится):

```
upn,ip,key,mv,mt,ms,ipbits,initcwndbps,cnr,signature,sver,ratebypass
```

Comment: Я видел эту статью. К сожалению видео, которые добавлены, например, в этом году, уже так не вытащишь. Если я не прав, то покажите, как это сделать, будк признателен

Comment: ответ должен кратко содержать суть и плюс сылку. И сервис не хабр. по тому и минус

Comment: Значительно дополнил ответ, добавил код своего успешного эксперимента. Спасибо за замечания.